# upgrading from ossec to wazuh - "local/standalone" mode?

Tags: splunk, ossec, wazuh

I am currently running ossec 3.6 in local mode and forwarding data to Splunk.  I cannot seem to find something similar in wazuh - am I missing something?  We really don't want to have a manager as all our data goes to Splunk anyway.  We'd like to continue outputting ossec/wazuh data in Splunk format and send straight to Splunk.  I've Googled and read the wazuh docs, but cannot find anything that addresses this. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to use standalone agents in Wazuh.

However, Wazuh managers also act as an standalone agent. Therefore, if the system you want to monitor is Linux, you can directly install the Wazuh-manager package there and it will take care of collecting and analyzing its local logs. Take a look at this doc, in case it helps [Migrating OSSEC server](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/migrating-from-ossec/ossec-server.html#ossec-server).

If your target version is different from Linux (Windows, macOS, etc), there is no alternative and you will have to install a Wazuh-manager on a linux instance that the agent can report to. Agents without a manager cannot do anything.

I hope this solves your question!

Comment: It does - thank you very much.  I'll go ahead and install the Manager on my Linux machines.  Appreciate it!